# Python remove backslashes from string

Tags: python

I need to change the following string - to remove the '\' from the string - using python:
'\'aaa_aaa\''-> 'aaa_aaa'

Tehila

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160752/removing-backslashes-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing backslashes from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160752/removing-backslashes-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: You can't. Inside a string that is delimited by `'` any other  `'` signifies the strings end. If you want to include literal `'` inside it you have to escape them or use other strings delimiters: `"Sam's bar"` or `''' multi'lines '''` or `"""other's"""`. It is just the way python displays a "literal" `'` - it escapes it. If you print it, you wont see the `\`

Answer (score 0):

Those backslashes are escape characters because your string starts and ends with the same apostrophes (delimited by them). If you want to avoid the using of the escape characters just do it:

```
"'aaa_aaa'"
```

But it is not that output what you want, you want to remove those apostrophes. So use strip:

```
'\'aaa_aaa\''.strip("'")

# or

"'aaa_aaa'".strip("'")
```

or replace:

```
'\'aaa_aaa\''.replace("'", "")

# or

"'aaa_aaa'".replace("'", "")
```

or you can use it if the apostrophes will be every times at the begin and end of the strings:

```
s = '\'aaa_aaa\''
s[1:-1]
```

Comment: And of course you also can uses multi line string delimiters how Patrick Artner said.